# Scraping dynamic data with Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have this simple page on html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Javascript (dynamic data) test:</p>
    <p class='jstest' id='yesnojs'>Hello</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('yesnojs').innerHTML = 'GoodBye';
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like now scrap this page using Python to get when the id "yesnojs" is "GoodBye", I mean, when the user has clicked the button. I have been trying some tutorials but I always get "Hello", it doesn´t care if I have click and I am viewing on the page "GoodBye".

I hope your help, thank you.

PD:
this is my code on Python for try scrape the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path=
"C:\\Users\\Antonio\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("http://localhost/templates/scraping.html")
review = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jstest")
for post in review:
    print(post.text)
```

Comment: Where is your code for scraping?

Comment: `document.getElementById('yesnojs').innerHTML` resides in RAM. Hence, I don't understand how you could get changed value by scraping the html file. I havn't done it so it more of a question.

Comment: Uploaded the code of Python

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not attach to your existing open web pages. It opens a new web page. You would have to simulate clicking with Selenium if you're designing a unit test.

Alternatively, are you looking at making a browser extension that does the scraping when this event happens, Selenium is not the tool for this.